# react native use state returns isLoading as a read only instead of setting is value to false

Tags: react-native

how can i change the isLoading state to false i'm trying this and i get the error setIsLoading is read only

```
 const[isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const[userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading=(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo in `setIsLoading=(false);`

change to `setIsLoading(false)`